# PayPal Buy button without 'Pay with a Card' option

Tags: paypal, paypal-buttons

I created a simple html form and put there a 'PayPal Buy Now' button: http://fortesting.edgework.com.ua/muzyka/price/popup.php. But when I press it, I see only 2 options:

1. Pay with my PayPal account.
2. Create a PayPal account.
   [image: only two pay options]

But I want to give my visitors an opportunity to pay with a credit card. I have read on this forum and from another sources several reasons why it so:

1. This option is forbidden in my country(Ukraine).
2. This option is legacy for all countries.

But the date of this posts was not recently and I have a doubt about its truthfulness. But the most interesting thing is that when I visit my button from android device, I see the 3d option: **3. Pay with a Card:**

[image]

The Android device is in the same network such my PC. Therefore the IP is the same. I want to know, why this difference is, and how to obtain **'Pay with a Card'** at my PC. 
Please, help. Thank you!

Comment: you realize your screenshot contains the words "and pay with your debit and credit card" right?  In any case, the option DOES exist.  however, it's not for personal accounts: https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/mer/WAX_landing-outside.  I recommend getting a business account.  The one I have was free, and gives me business options (even though i don't think the button has been clicked once by a non-developer)

Comment: Thank you. Business account = I`m happy)

Answer (score 0):

The merchant account email address must be confirmed for the credit card option to display on the hosted page.